# How to inherit property values in a UserControl?

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app, custom-controls

I have a page where I am adding a custom control like this:

```
<custom:ClickableIcon x:Name="DeleteTask" Grid.Column="2" Foreground="Red" Icon="Delete" Click="DeleteTask_Click" />
```

In my custom control, I have the following XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Name="clickableIconUserControl"
    x:Class="Client.UWP.Controls.ClickableIcon"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Client.UWP.Controls" IsEnabledChanged="userControl_IsEnabledChanged">

    <Grid x:Name="ohmygrid">
        <SymbolIcon x:Name="CIIcon"
                    Foreground="{Binding Foreground, ElementName=clickableIconUserControl}"
                    Symbol="{Binding Icon, ElementName=clickableIconUserControl}"
                    Tapped="CIIcon_Tapped"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

This doesn't actually work.  What I want is to copy the Foreground property for the control into specific places in the user control.  I'd like to do this within a style sheet, direct property or whatever.  In addition, I'd like to update the foreground when the foreground of the control on the page is changed.

Unfortunately, in this code (which is much simplified than the code I am actually trying to write), the Foreground is always #FF000000 in the debugger and I cannot seem to get a hold of the setting on the actual control to set it - either in code behind or as a binding.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I just tried your code snippet,foreground and Icon property is updating for me. May be you have to post entire code to see where is the mistake

Comment: I can confirm that as well.

Comment: Just to follow up (since I completely failed when I asked the question), some wierdity with VS must have been causing this.  I re-installed VS, and it started working as described.